# Dpkg-reconfigure in BASH

Tags: bash, debian, dpkg

I've recently done a script that reconfigures all packages on a Debian Stable (7.3) system. I'm using the command

```
    dpkg-reconfigure -pcritical -a --force
```

Everything worked fine, but today I made some changes to the code (I don't think they are related) and now I'm getting this error:

```
Can't exec "dpkg-query": Not a directory at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 98.
Can't exec "dpkg": Not a directory at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 82.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 83.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 84.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 85.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 86.
Can't exec "dpkg-query": Not a directory at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 98.
Can't exec "dpkg": Not a directory at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 82.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 83.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 84.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 85.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 86.
Can't exec "dpkg-query": Not a directory at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 98.
Can't exec "dpkg-query": Not a directory at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 202.
readline() on closed filehandle QUERY at /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure line 204.
```

There are thousands of lines full of similar lines (these are the last ones).
The system is running in runlevel 1 - single-user - and as user root. And another interesting thing is that dpkg exit code is still 0.

Thank you for your help in advance.

EDIT: here's the script

```
#!/bin/bash
DPKG_RECONFIG_PATH=/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure
# Function for checking critical executables (exits on error)
chk_crit ()
{
TARGET=$1
PATH=$2
if [ -e $PATH ] # Pass 1 - checking existence
then printf "$TARGET exists\n"
else
    printf "$TARGET doesn't exist!\n"
    exit
fi
if [ -x $PATH ] # Pass 2 - checking execution permissions
then
    printf "$TARGET is executable\n"
else
    printf "$TARGET is not executable, attempting chmod!\n"
    chmod 755 $TARGET_PATH
    CHMOD_EXIT=$?
    if [ $CHMOD_EXIT = 0 ] # Checking if chmod has succeeded
    then
        printf "chmod succeeded\n"
else
        printf "chmod failed, $TARGET is unusable!\n"
        exit
    fi
fi
}

chk_crit dpkg-reconfigure $DPKG_RECONFIG_PATH

# Reconfiguring all packages, only asking critical questions
$DPKG_RECONFIG_PATH -pcritical -a --force
DPKG_EXIT=$?
if [ $DPKG_EXIT = 0 ]
then printf "Reconfiguration succeeded\n"
else printf "Reconfiguration failed\n"
exit $DPKG_EXIT
fi
exit
```

Comment: Looks like some unrelated change broke some related system component. Did you manually change permissions or delete something?

Comment: There's a function in my script which runs chmod 755 on dpkg-reconfigure in case it's not executable, but the logfile tells that it haven't done anything, dpkg was found in usable format. Also, when I run dpkg-reconfigure manually, it succeeds.

Comment: I don't think that's related, either, but it's not a very good idea. If `dpkg` was not correctly installed, you should reinstall it rather than try to manually fix up individual symptoms. It's probably also reasonable to assume that your current problems were caused by some similar "safeguard".

Comment: I'm sure that dpkg is installed correctly, I checked it manually. It only fails when called from the script.

Comment: Probably you'll need to post the script to get meaningful answer.

Comment: `chmod 755 $TARGET_PATH` is buggy because `$TARGET_PATH` is never set

Comment: _another interesting thing is that dpkg exit code is still 0_: according to the error message, `dpkg` cannot be executed at all. Where do you see an exit code?

Comment: Daniel, good point that $TARGET_PATH is never set, that remained from a previous version. I know the exit code as I temporarily implemented a line that printed $?.

Comment: And I corrected `$TARGET_PATH` to `$PATH`, thanks for it! But it doesn't solve the problem as it never executes if dpkg is executable.

Comment: If you reset the system variable `PATH`, that's the reason things are failing. This is a reserved variable which the shell uses to find commands.

Comment: I know that `$PATH` is important, but as you can see, I use absolute path to dpkg. Does dpkg itself uses `$PATH` as well? And also, how does `$PATH` go blank if I don't do it? It works outside the script if I do `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Oh how could I be so stupid... Now I got it, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sorry for the question as it was absolutely my mistake. Thank you for all those who helped me  recognize the bug.

The script didn't work as I accidentally used `$PATH` as a name for one of my custom variables. It reset the real `$PATH` and prevented dpkg execute correctly. Now  I corrected it to `$TARGET_PATH` and everything works fine. Once again, sorry for being so careless.